# NextJS getStaticProps with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, next.js, getstaticprops

I'm following a NextJS course, however I want to use Typescript - I've read a github discussion forum, but cannot seem to understand why there is an error on the 1st function below, but not the second?

```
export async function getStaticProps(): GetStaticProps {
    return {
        props: {
            example:  ""
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get for the above function is the following:

> The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise type. Did you mean to write 'Promise<GetStaticProps<{ [key: string]: any; }, ParsedUrlQuery, PreviewData>>'?

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    return {
        props: {
            example: ""
        }
    }
};
```

However I do not get this error for the function above, why is that? What's the difference I thought these 2 functions are the same by definition, one is an arrow function while the other is a regular function?

Can someone please explain how I can use the first function with the appropriate TypeScript types? What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

In the first function, your type specification is of the *return type* of the function. In the second function, your type specification is of the type of the function *itself*.

For example, these 2 functions are of the same type, but where you specify the type matters.

```
const hi: () => string = () => {
    return "a"
}

const hi2 = (): string => {
    return "a"
}
```

To answer your second question, all async functions must have return a Promise. As your first function returned `GetStaticProps` which is not a promise, it gives an error. The way to fix it would be to specify the return type as `Promise<GetStaticProps>` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand now that the 1st function is declaring the return type of the function and as an async function it should return a Promise, however wrapping it with a Promise will still result in a compilation issue.

How would one specify the 'type' of a Function using regular functional syntax (not an arrow function)? 

I took a look at GetStaticProps type definition and it does indeed define a type of Function.

Comment: You can do something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAtgngggEwQLggCgB6oHYFcoBGIATgDQQw75HECUEAvAHwR6EmMQBmu2AxmACWAe2zoAUBAhZW1EqUkUq7YuNrKaEAN6Li4XMTEYIAagoBucQF9zQA)